# Does $A-\lambda I$ have rank smaller than $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider $\lambda$ as one eigenvalue of $A$, can we say that $A-\lambda I$ must have rank smaller than $A$? Or equivalently, $A-\lambda I$ spans a space which is a subset of $A$?

Comment: A singular matrix has $\lambda=0$ as an eigenvalue.

Comment: What does "a subset of $A$" mean when $A$ is a matrix?

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider an $n$-dimensional matrix $A$ that is $0$ except for $a_{11} = c \neq 0$. 
Then $c$ is an eigenvalue, yet $A - c I$ has rank $n-1$ while the rank of $A$ is $1$.

More generally the rank of $A-cI $ is $n$ minus the (geometric) multiplicity of the eigenvalue and at least $n$ minus the arithmetic multiplicity of the eigenvalue that is the multiplicity of the root in the characteristic polynomial.

Then, the rank of $A - cI$ is never $n$, so for an invertible matrix it would be true.